# Serialized Results too large PySpark Left Join

Tags: optimization, pyspark, out-of-memory, databricks

I have a problem with a last "left" join of a transformation.

The result continually returns me the following error: `There is too much data being sent to the driver. 4.0 GiB of serialized data from 10700 tasks exceeds the limit of 4.0 GiB.` and not so how to fix it.

The final desired dataset contains 4.5 million rows and shouldn't be complicated to obtain. I have already disabled the join broadcast but to no avail.

**Edit for deepening:**
The join is located at the last line of the code (which involves more or less heavy operations) but this is precisely where it stops. Without this join, in fact, I can build both datasets (df and df2). Then when I execute the join it returns me the error.

```
df --> ~2.500.000 rows, 3 columns, 24.5 MB size. (Result of F.explode of DATE for each ID

df2 --> ~700.000 rows, 10 columns, 29.5 MB size. (Result of union of some datasets)

df_final = df.join(df2, ['ID', 'DATE'], 'left')
```

Please help me! Thank u!

Comment: Please add code and sample data.

Comment: Edited, thank u!

Comment: are you running this in cluster?   does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948714/joining-a-large-and-a-ginormous-spark-dataframe?

Comment: Have you confirmed this final row count using a count on df_final? Also what action are performing which causes the data to be sent to the driver node? (e.g. toPandas?)

Comment: I have built datasets separately (so i know the size). The problem is when i try to join them.